# Memberships not recorded since mid April 2018 (using Webform)

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

Civi 4.7.27

I use extensively Webform Integration to register Memberships.

Since mid April (precisely April 21st, but I don't remember when I did some Module Updates), memberships have not been recorded anymore, though no error message is displayed and Webform Mails are sent (and received).

Some information before further investigation :

- My memberships have no associated Contribution and are for Life
- They have some associated multi-valued Custom Fields
- When they contain a new Contact, the new Contact is not created either
- I have the same problem on a Test Civi 5.0.0 configuration

I will report this as a bug to https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/webform_civicrm, and keep this informed if I find other informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation it appears that :

The problem occurs when you define a Membership custom multi-valued field, even if you specify it as "non required", both in its definition and in the Webform :

If you don't specify at least one value in the Webform, the membership will not be recorded : this means that you have to define this field as required in the webform if you don't want to have the problem.

From my point of view, this is only a partial answer : this issue should be answered :

- either, at least, by a message which tells that the membership will not be recorded, due to ...
- or by recording the membership, even with this field empty,
- or by locking this field as required in the webform,
- or ...

I will edit my bug report in this way at https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/2968720#comment-12598952.

Here under (suggested by Karin and Pete) some screenshots to explain how the field was specified to produce this failure :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok so can you paste me a screenshot of this field as defined in your CiviCRM -> Custom Data etc.

Comment: Jacques - you should 1/ accept your own answer 2/ paste those screenshots in this answer, not add them as a separate answer is it will end up getting down voted

Answer (score 2):

ok let’s figure this out:

- add the webform_civicrm module version + civicrm version to your question
- check if there are any drupal database updates to be executed
- use (install if you don’t have it yet) node_clone module to clone your webform
- on the cloned form: remove the multi-value fileds - check if the form works without them
- use (install if you don’t have it yet) https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer to view any configandlog file entries;

Let us know what clues you can dig up.

Comment: Nice answer Karin

Comment: Thank you Karin ; but after further investigation, I found the answer (see my answer)